# How much of the chemical will be in the pond after a very long time?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A pond initially containing 1000000 gal of water and an unknown amount of undesirable chemical. Water containing 0.01 gram of this chemical per gallon flows into the pond at a rate of 300 gal/hr. The mixture flows out at the same rate, so the amount of water in the pond remains constant. Assume that the chemical is uniformly distributed throughout the pond.

How much of the chemical will be in the pond after a very long time? Does the limiting amount depend on the amount that was present initially?

I already solved and found my DEQ to be 
$$
\frac{dQ}{dt} = 3-0.0003Q(t)
$$
I just don't understand what part b is asking for?

Comment: Probably wants you to take the limit of $Q$ as $t \rightarrow \infty$ and comment on how the initial amount would affect that answer, if at all.

Comment: But the DEQ is autonomous... I don't even have t in the equation. Am I suppose to solve it first and then take the limit?

Comment: Yes, I would say that is exactly what you are supposed to do. The solution will have $t$ in it and the limit as $t\to\infty$ will be obvious.